# Instantaneous power delivered in a string

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string, constrained-dynamics

When the supports of a string are moving, why is the instantaneous power delivered by the string $0$?

So we say that at all moving contacts of the string, $$\sum \vec{T_i}\cdot \vec{v_i}=0$$ where $T$ and $v$ are the tensions and velocities at a point.
We often use this method to solve the problems of constrained motion in mechanics.
I want to know the proof of this method.

Comment: Tension is an internal force in the problems you might be doing, which means it does zero net work (positive on one, neg on other), and power is just derivative of work wrto time

Comment: I want a proper rigorous proof, what you have said may definitely be the essence of the proof...

Comment: See [D'Alembert's principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_principle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internal forces doesn't accomplishes work (such as tension in *constrained-dynamics* systems,- pulleys, etc.). Thus :
$$ W=\vec{T_1} \cdot \vec{s_1} + \vec{T_2} \cdot \vec{s_2} + \ldots + \vec{T_n} \cdot \vec{s_n} = 0 $$
Where $\vec{s}$ are displacement vectors.  Differentiating with respect to time, we get :

$$ \vec{T_1} \frac{d \vec{s_1}}{dt} + \vec{T_2} \frac{d \vec{s_2}}{dt}  + \ldots + \vec{T_n} \frac{d \vec{s_n}}{dt} = 0 $$

Which is :

$$ \vec{T_1} ~\vec{v_1} + \vec{T_2} ~\vec{v_2}  + \ldots + \vec{T_n} ~\vec{v_n} = 0 $$

Or simply in short notation :

$$ \sum_i \vec{T_i} ~ \vec{v_i} = 0 $$

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the work done by tension is $0$? Suppose we have a string of length $l$, and we stretch it by $\mathrm{d}l$, and tension generated in the string would be $\mathrm{d}T$, so how would the work done be $0$?

Comment: This question analysis _constrained motion_ (not every motion), of which simple example is system of pulleys. In such constrained systems usually chain between objects is idealized as an **inextensible** connection. Thus you can't stretch a rope(s) in pulley systems, or more exactly if you do that - you can't apply given law here and must use a different principles.

Comment: So does that further imply $\sum \vec{T_i}\vec{a_i}=0$ ?

Comment: I suppose yes, you can take second derivative of displacement with respect to time and you will get acceleration.